# How to construct an arbitrary 2-regular detachment of a connected graph whose vertices are all of even degree?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, graph, graph-theory

### TL;DR

How can I construct an arbitrary 2-regular detachment of a connected graph whose vertices are all of even degree? Appropriate algorithms, data structures? Pseudocode? Any actual implementation?

### Definitions

**D1**: A graph H will be said to be *2-regular* if every vertex of H has degree 2.

**D2**: A *detachment* H of a graph G is a graph obtained from G by splitting some of its vertices into more than one vertex, and sharing the incident edges arbitrarily among the subvertices (see [Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cKKG.png)).

**Problem**: I want to write a program in Java to construct an *arbitrary 2-regular detachment* H of a connected graph G whose vertices are all of even degree (see [Figure 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Io1Zv.png)).

### What I've done so far

I googled for pseudocode and an actual implementation, but I didn't find anything relevant except for the following theorem: "Given a connected graph G whose vertices are all of even degree, *the edge set of G can be partitioned into cycles, no two of which share an edge*". There is also a constructive proof of the theorem below. I'm not really sure if the sentence in italics is equivalent to the "arbitrary 2-regular detachment" I'm looking for. They look the same to me though. A verification would be appreciated.

**Proof** (in brief): Choose a vertex u of G. Produce a trail T starting at u by traversing at each step any edge not yet traversed. Continue this trail, until we reach a vertex v that we have met before (v may or may not be the same vertex as u). The edges of the trail between the two occurencies of v must form a cycle. Call this cycle C1. If C1 covers all the edges of G, then we are done. Otherwise, remove the edges forming C1 from the graph G, leaving the graph G1. Pick some vertex u' in G1. Repeat the same process as before. Generate a cycle C2. If C2 covers all the rest of the edges of G, then we are done. Otherwise, remove the edges forming C2 from the graph G1, leaving the graph G2. We continue in this way until we have used up all the edges of G. By this time we have a number of cycles C1, C2, ..., Ck which between them contain all the edges of G but no two of them have an edge in common.

Since the proof is constructive, I wrote a program in Java following *some* steps of the proof (see *generateCycle()*). **Additionally, I remove from the graph all edges traversed**. I use the graph shown in **Figure 2** as input. There is still room for improvement in terms of correctness (some outputs are not correct), complexity (choosing appropriate data structures, algorithms), design etc. Again, as I previously stated, I'm not sure if this method always constructs an *arbitrary 2-regular detachment*.

**Graph.java**

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class Graph<V> {
    Set<V> vertices = new HashSet<V>();
    Map<V, Set<V>> edges = new HashMap<V, Set<V>>();

    public void addEdge(V v1, V v2) {
        vertices.add(v1);
        vertices.add(v2);
        Set<V> e1 = edges.get(v1);
        if(e1 == null) {
            e1 = new HashSet<V>();
            edges.put(v1, e1);
        }
        e1.add(v2);
        Set<V> e2 = edges.get(v2);
        if(e2 == null) {
            e2 = new HashSet<V>();
            edges.put(v2, e2);
        }
        e2.add(v1);
    }

    public void removeEdge(V v1, V v2) {
        Set<V> e1 = edges.get(v1);
        e1.remove(v2);
        if(e1.isEmpty()) {
            edges.remove(v1);
            vertices.remove(v1);
        }
        Set<V> e2 = edges.get(v2);
        e2.remove(v1);
        if(e2.isEmpty()) {
            edges.remove(v2);
            vertices.remove(v2);
        }
    }

    public Set<V> getNeighbors(V v) {
        return edges.get(v);
    }
}
```

**Main.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class Main {
    public static <V> ArrayList<V> generateCycle(Graph<V> graph, V start) {
        V current = start;
        ArrayList<V> trail = new ArrayList<V>();
        ArrayList<V> cycle = new ArrayList<V>();
        boolean metBefore = false;
        while (!metBefore) {
            trail.add(current);
            Set<V> neighbors = graph.getNeighbors(current);
            if (neighbors == null) {
                break;
            }
            V next = neighbors.iterator().next();
            graph.removeEdge(current, next);
            current = next;
            int index; // index of first occurrence
            if ((index = trail.indexOf(current)) != -1) {
                metBefore = true;
                for (int i = index; i < trail.size(); i++) {
                    cycle.add(trail.get(i));
                }
                cycle.add(current);
            }
        }
        return cycle;
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Graph<String> g = new Graph<String>();
        g.addEdge("1", "2"); g.addEdge("2", "1");
        g.addEdge("1", "5"); g.addEdge("5", "1");
        g.addEdge("2", "5"); g.addEdge("5", "2");
        g.addEdge("2", "4"); g.addEdge("4", "2");
        g.addEdge("2", "3"); g.addEdge("3", "2");
        g.addEdge("3", "4"); g.addEdge("4", "3");
        g.addEdge("4", "5"); g.addEdge("5", "4");
        g.addEdge("4", "6"); g.addEdge("6", "4");
        g.addEdge("6", "5"); g.addEdge("5", "6");

        List<String> vertices = new ArrayList<String>();
        vertices.add("1"); vertices.add("2"); vertices.add("3");
        vertices.add("4"); vertices.add("5"); vertices.add("6");

        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> cycles = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

        for (String v : vertices) {
            cycles.add(generateCycle(g, v));
        }

        System.out.println(cycles);
    }
}
```

**Output**: [[2, 3, 4, 2], [], [], [4, 5, 6, 4], [], []]

Clearly, the cycle **[1, 2, 5, 1]** is missing because I removed the edge **1-2** while producing the trail 1->**2->3->4->2.** The output is not correct.

So, how can I construct an arbitrary 2-regular detachment of G?

Comment: even if you dont remove the 1-2 edge, I have the impression that when you start from 5, you'll find 2-3-4-2 again

Comment: No, I won't find 2-3-4-2 again (tested). Check the last for-loop in main().

Answer (score 1):

If all the vertices have even degree, you could create an Eularian Path (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path ).

In the eularian path, you could split every vertex that you visit multiple times (i.e. has more than two edges) can be split. While splitting make sure that the graph remains connected.